# Linking / associating a hidden value to a specific radio button on a form (PHP/MySQL/HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am creating a form using PHP which is linked to a MySQL database.

I have multiple questions, each requiring a yes or no response.

I have already set up the form so that the Yes and No responses submit to the database. However, if the user selects No, I need a hidden value (predefined details of why No would be selected) to be submitted to a different table on the database. Currently, when it submits, it submits the hidden value regardless of whether the user selects yes or no.

My code is as follows:

```
<label for="question1" class="input_labels">1. Confidentiality protocols were adhered to</label>
                                <input class="form-check-input-line" type="radio" name="question1" id="question1" value="YES">  YES
                                <input class="form-check-input-line" type="radio" name="question1" id="question1" value="NO">  NO <br>
                                <input type="hidden" id="error1" name="error1" value="Confidentiality protocols were not adhered to">
```

query1 is to submit the actual Yes / No responses and query2 is to submit the hidden value (I haven't added all the details to query2 yet as i am trying to test if it works first):

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO questions 
        
                    (questionsID, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10, question11, question12, question13, question14, question15, question16, question17, question18, question19, question20, question21, question22, question23, question24) 

                 VALUES 
                 
                    (NULL, '$question1', '$question2', '$question3', '$question4', '$question5', '$question6', '$question7', '$question8', '$question9', '$question10', '$question11', '$question12', '$question13', '$question14', '$question15', '$question16', '$question17', '$question18', '$question19', '$question20', '$question21', '$question22', '$question23', '$question24')";

        $result1 = mysqli_query( $conn, $query1);   
        
        } else {
    
        $submitError = "The form was not submitted, please try again <br>";

}

$query2 = "INSERT INTO fixable_errors 
        
                    (fixableID, error1) 

                 VALUES 
                 
                    (NULL, '$error1')";

        $result2 = mysqli_query( $conn, $query2);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that gets the data from the form and submits it, let's see were you might have gotten it wrong

Comment: put more code. It is still unclear

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman noted, thanks! And i'll definitely check out the frameworks you recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i expected you to post your JavaScript code, but nevertheless what you need to do is to disable the hidden input field only if the user selects the YES radio button, that way, the hidden input doesn't get submitted along with the rest.

**JS**

```
var radioBtns = document.getElementsByName("question1");
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("error1");

radioBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var radioValue = this.value;
        if (radioValue == "Yes") { // case-sensitive
            hiddenInput.setAttribute("disabled", "");
        } else {
            hiddenInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

The code above disables the hidden field when the user clicks YES and enables it when the user clicks NO.

And now in your PHP code, you can check if the hidden field's value was submitted too using the `isset()` function. See code below

**PHP**

```
// check if input with name 'error1' was submitted
if(isset($_POST['error1']){
    $error1 = $_POST['error1'];
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO fixable_errors (fixableID, error1) VALUES (NULL, '$error1')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query( $conn, $query2);
}
```

Comment: @Ryan You're welcome, do well to mark this answer as accepted 

Comment: This still has some **extremely dangerous** SQL injection in it.

Comment: @tadman Well I believe he knows that he should validate any input coming from the form and escape them before use. His question was based on sending the hidden input on a condition that the a specific radio button was selected

Comment: Escaping can be forgotten. Placeholder values ensure the values are handled properly.